# Robot Framework and Python Logging: Logging from multiple threads and logging channel names

Tags: python, logging, robotframework

I use Python standard logging extensively in my libraries within my Robot Framework test suites. These log messages are appearing in the RF log, as expected, save for two problems:

1. Some of the libraries create threads. Log messages on these additional threads do not reach the RF log.
2. For each library I follow the standard practice of creating a logging channel named after the module/class `self._logger = logging.getLogger( __name__ )` , but I cannot seem to format the logging in any way to get these channel names to appear in the RF logs.

If I run these libraries from regular Python scripts, instead of RF, I get log messages from the additional threads, and I can format all messages to show the channel names. So there is some issue when using them within RF.

I'm using RF3, Python3 and running under Raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the Robot Framework User Guide:

"Messages logged by non-main threads using the normal logging methods from programmatic logging APIs are silently ignored."

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#communication-when-using-threads

You could try this user contributed module as a workaround:

https://github.com/robotframework/robotbackgroundlogger